# React-native-maps Map page is unstable, flickering and scrolling downwards

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

[Unstable MapView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC0WA.gif)

Map page is unstable, flickering and scrolling downwards. There are zoom buttons on the Map page and I am using onRegionChangeComplete.

```
 const onRegionChange2 = (e) => {
        const regionChangeValue = {
            latitude: e.latitude,
            longitude: e.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: e.latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: e.longitudeDelta
        }
        setRegion(regionChangeValue)
        map?.current?.animateToRegion(regionChangeValue, 1000)
    }
```

```
 <MapView
                ref={map}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                zoomEnabled={true}
                followsUserLocation={true}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                toolbarEnabled={false}
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChange2}
                >
...
```

i try animateToRegion but its doesnt help.

Comment: i remove this  line "map?.current?.animateToRegion(regionChangeValue, 1000)" and solved .